How can I send notifications from Flutter with FCM?
I'm trying to send notifications with Firebase Cloud Messages from Flutter, the thing is that if the notification event is received on the other device, the problem comes from _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin which does not show the notification and sends me the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'android.content.Intent
android.content.Intent.setAction(java.lang.String)' on a null object
reference.

Before starting to send notifications from flutter, I tried from the same firebase console and I got the same error, but I solved it in the AndroidManifest by removing an intent-filtrer that said FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK and now with that code and without it the error continues to appear.
NotificationService:
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class PushNotifications {
  static final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  // request notification permission
  static Future init() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: true,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  // initalize local notifications
  static Future localNotiInit() async {
    // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings(
      '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
    );
    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) {},
    );
    const LinuxInitializationSettings initializationSettingsLinux =
        LinuxInitializationSettings(defaultActionName: 'Open notification');
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
            linux: initializationSettingsLinux);

    // request notification permissions for android 13 or above
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
        .requestNotificationsPermission();

    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onNotificationTap,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onNotificationTap,
    );
  }

  static void onNotificationTap(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    // navigatorKey.currentState!
    //     .pushNamed("/message", arguments: notificationResponse);
  }

  static Future showSimpleNotification({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
  }) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('ch1', 'ch1',
            channelDescription: 'simplechannel',
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max,
            playSound: true,
            enableVibration: true,
            ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, notificationDetails, payload: payload); //error aquí
  }
}


FirebaseMessagingService Here is the logic to send the notification:

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart' as auth;
import 'package:googleapis/servicecontrol/v1.dart' as servicecontrol;

final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final url = Uri.parse(
    'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectname/messages:send');

getAceessToken() async {
  final serviceAccountJson = {
   // Your service account json
  };
  List<String> scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging',
  ];

  http.Client client = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(
    auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(serviceAccountJson),
    scopes,
  );

  // Get the access token
  auth.AccessCredentials credentials =
      await auth.obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(
          auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(serviceAccountJson),
          scopes,
          client);

  client.close();
  return credentials.accessToken.data;
}

sendPushMessage(
  String uid,
  String title,
  String bodyText,
  bool saveIn,
) async {
  List tokens = await getUserTokens(uid);

  final String accessToken = await getAceessToken();

  if (tokens.isEmpty) {
    return http.Response('No tokens found', 400);
  }

  for (var tokenData in tokens) {
    String token = tokenData['token'];
    final body = jsonEncode({
      'message': {
        'token': token,
        'notification': {
          'title': title,
          'body': bodyText.toString(),
        },
        'data': {
          'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
          'id': '1',
          'status': 'done'
        }
      },
    });

    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        },
        body: body,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        log('Message sent to $token');
        if (saveIn) {
          //saveInFirestore(uid, title, bodyText);
        }
      } else {
        print(response.body);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

void saveInFirestore(String uid, String title, String body) {
  _firestore.collection('USERS').doc(uid).collection('NOTIFICATIONS').add({
    'title': title,
    'body': body,
    'date': DateTime.now().toString(),
    'viewed': false,
    'idNotification': const Uuid().v4(),
  }).then((doc) {
    _firestore.collection('USERS').doc(uid).update({'id_document': doc.id});
  });
}

Future<List> getUserTokens(String uid) async {
  List tokens = [];
  try {
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await _firestore.collection('USERS').doc(uid).get();
    tokens = (snap.data()! as dynamic)['tokens'];
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
  return tokens;
}

AndroidManifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:label="MoodU"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                         android:host="example.com"
                        android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
            <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
   android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    </application>
   
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


Hi, only English on Stack Overflow

You have to use FCM Api to send notification from flutter.
You can implement api directly in flutter or integarte in backend side then in flutter.
Docs refer : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest
URL:
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Header:
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Authorization": "key=<Server_key>"

BODY:
{
    "to": "<Device FCM token>",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Check this Mobile (title)",
      "body": "Rich Notification testing (body)",
      "mutable_content": true,
      "sound": "Tri-tone"
      },

   "data": {
    "url": "<url of media image>",
    "dl": "<deeplink action on tap of notification>"
      }
}

For more updated check firebase docs
